# How to keep a reference of marker in iOS Google Maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

So according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker#remove_a_marker), I need to keep a reference to the marker. Right now, in my `viewWillDisappear` method I'm trying to clear one of the pins off the map but it's not working. Maybe it's because I don't have a reference to it? If so, how does that work? (By the way, I couldn't get it to work as a part of any other method as well, not just `viewWillDisappear`.)

I have the latitude and longitude of the marker and here's what I'm doing now:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[passedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue], [[passedCoordinates objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue]);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.map = nil;
```

But it's not clearing. Any advice?

#### Update:

I'm keeping a reference now and this is how I'm trying to find which marker to clear:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    if (passedCoordinates.count != 0) {
        for (GMSMarker *markerRef in _markerRefs){
            if (markerRef.position.latitude == [[passedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue] && markerRef.position.longitude == [[passedCoordinates objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue]) {
                NSLog(@"here");
                markerRef.map = nil;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the log output that it's finding the correct marker but it's not going away. I added a button on the navigation bar just to click and remove the marker with the same function but it's still on the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `markerWithPosition:` its creating a new object with given position. It will not return your old marker object's pointer with that position. 
When you creating your markers, you should keep it in an array:

```
@interface YourClass()

// Declaring array that will hold all markers
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *allMarkers;

//...
@end

@implementation

//...
- (void)yourMethod
{
     if (!self.allMarkers) {
         self.allMarkers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }

   // Here, when you creating your markers and adding to self.mapView
      CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[passedCoordinates objectAtIndex:0]doubleValue], [[passedCoordinates objectAtIndex:1]doubleValue]);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
      marker.map  = self.mapView;

   // add allocated markers to allMarkers array
     [self.allMarkers addObject:marker]
}

//...
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    for (GMSMarker *marker in self.allMarkers) {
        // Remove marker from the map
        marker.map = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...it makes sense but I still can't get it to work.  Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: Can you add a piece of code where you initialize and add markers to the map? 
And ин which method you are doing it?

Comment: I've been messing with the code...it's a problem with what I'm doing, your example is correct.  I'll try to fix my adding references, removing and getting marker methods.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I do still have a question.  Problem I'm having is I'm removing a marker and adding one at that same location.  After adding, I can't seem to remove it.  When removing the first marker, do I need to remove it's reference too and then add another reference of the second marker?  I'm referencing them based on location (latitude and longitude) so I shouldn't have to add another reference for the second marker, should I?

Comment: It depends on what logic do you want to implement

Comment: If I'm playing the second marker in the same location (basically just changing the image around), shouldn't I be able to reference the second marker with the reference locations of the first?  But for some reason that's not working...

Comment: If you must have only 1 marker at the same time, then you can just declare a strong pointer for that marker instead of array, like: 
@property (strong, nonatomic) GMSMarker *marker; 

and change characteristic of that marker when you need (e.g. change position, icon, etc). 
I mean if you want to change position of marker which is already visible on the map, then no need to create a new marker with new position, you can just change position of existing one.