# iOS Google Maps: how to "keep hold" of a marker? Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

newbie starting out. I want to remove a unique marker I have previously added. The documentation says I must "keep hold" and keep reference of it to delete an old marker. Not sure how to do that?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343769/how-to-keep-a-reference-of-marker-in-ios-google-maps) seems to be the answer, but I don't really know how to convert it to Swift 4? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create an array and store your markers in the array for future use.

```swift
var markerArray = [GMSMarker]()

//When you create markers, append them to the array
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.map = map
markerArray.append(marker)
```

To remove

```swift
for marker in markerArray {
    marker.map = nil
}
```